# Add an element in arraylist of arraylist using index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a arrayList done this way:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> level = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(levels + 1);
```

So something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAP1D.png)

What I would do is add a new element to the internal list saved in a certain index `i` of the external list.
How can I do this?

I can't use method `arrayList.add(i, 0.0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the list at a given position first and then insert into it the value desired.

## Example:

```
final List<List<Double>> listOnList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
listOnList.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
listOnList.get(0).add(155.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use index from the external `ArrayList` and use it to add the number. Like this

```
level.get(i).add(1.1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why I get an `out of bound exception` if I try to add something in index 1?

Comment: @lon What is `i` and what is the size of `level`?

Comment: `i=1` and the size of level is 4

Comment: I solved using `listOnList.add(new ArrayList<Double>());`, thanks!

Comment: @lon was just about to write you need to initialize the inner `ArrayList<Double>`, not only `level`. Good luck :)